# Transformation of a Cauchy-Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone explain to me how I would go about transforming a Cauchy-Euler equation into a constant coefficient equation for:

$x^2y'' - xy' = \ln x$

I know you have to start with $x = e^t$ or $t = \ln x$ however I'm not sure what to do next...

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y'' - xy' = x(xy'' - y')$$ Note that $(xy'' - y')$ is like $uv' - u'v$ which is $u^2 \dfrac{d}{du}\left(\dfrac{v}u\right)$. Hence, we have
$$x(xy'' - y') = x^3 \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{y'}{x}\right)$$
Hence, we have
$$x^3 \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{y'}{x}\right) = \ln(x) \implies \dfrac{y'}x = \int \dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^3} dx + \text{constant}$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{y'}x = - \dfrac{1+2\ln(x)}{4x^2} + \text{constant} \implies y' = - \dfrac{1+2\ln(x)}{4x} + cx$$
This gives us
$$y(x) = -\dfrac14 \ln(x)(1+\ln(x)) + k_1 x^2 + k_2$$